# Is it possible with laravel to go from post.store to post.edit?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I can't figure out how to go from a store method directly to a edit page.

Routes:

```
Route::post('/', 'PostController@store')->name('posts.store');
Route::get('/', 'PostController@edit')->name('posts.edit');
```

post controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $post->save();

    return view('posts.edit');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    dd('edit post');
}
```

I keep getting view not found or other errors. I have checked php artisan route:list and the correct route is there. What am i missing here?

Comment: Normally when you are done saving the user to the database you give the user a redirect to an overview page. So just redirect the user to the edit route. `return redirect('user/' . $post->id . '/edit')->with('user_id', $post->id);` If all is correct you should see `edit post`. You can then use the `$user_id` variable in your edit route on the edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should do a `redirect` to the route instead. See [Redirecting to Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

So this should work:

```
return redirect()->route('posts.edit');
```

At this point, you are trying to load a view.

Comment: Thank you! I tried so much that I got lost but this fixed it!